# 1146 Table doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, mysql-error-1064, joomla3.4

I get the follow Error 1146 Message:

> Table 'system.qbruw_extensions' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT * FROM qbruw_extensions WHERE element='com_imageshow' AND type='component

Reinstall of the component doesn't fix the Problem.

`qbruw_extensions` is existing in the Joomla MySQL Database

`com_imageshow` Folder is existing in the Components Folder of Joomla

Joomla Database repair doesn't fix the problem.

Joomla 3.4.1 is installed...

Comment: It looks like you haven't selected the right database. It assumes you want to work in the `system` database, which is probably not the case. Change to the proper database.

Comment: i got a "system" database - but this was never used for joomla.  Joomla Database is called "dbjoomla". The Joomla Backend is right configur'd to use "dbjoomla".   There can i change it ?

Comment: Is the `qbruw_extensions` table in that database? What happens if you write `FROM dbjoomla.qbruw_extensions`?

Comment: `SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'system'
AND table_name = 'qbruw_extensions';`

Comment: what is this component ? its a public extension ? can you give me the link ?

Comment: @Rockstar - the system.qbruw_extensions dosn't exist in the system Database...  Maybe how can i'm tell this the Joomla or the Database, that it have to use the dbjoomla.qbruw_extensions

Comment: @Silverboy JSN ImageShow from joomlashine.com

Comment: and in which page you are getting the error ?

Comment: I include a PHP Script via "Nonumber Sourcerer Extentsion" in a normal article. This article is binded to the a main menu field in the frontend.

Comment: I copy'd the qbruw_extensions into the system database -> Now i get the next missing table...  There can i change this that joomla have to use his own "dbjoomla" Database and not the "system" database ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM dbjoomla.qbruw_extensions WHERE element='com_imageshow' AND type='component'
```

---

**Solution : For next missing table**

Either you export all the required tables from `dbjoomla` and import those into `system` database

OR

Use [JDatabaseDriver->getInstance](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html#getInstance) method to connect external database

Comment: It's there...  but why try joomla to read the table from system.qbruw_extensions ? it have to use dbjoomla.qbruw_extensions :/

Comment: I copy'd the qbruw_extensions into the system database -> Now i get the next missing table...  There can i change this that joomla have to use his own "dbjoomla" Database and not the "system" database ?